# Integrate ABBYY with React Native

Tags: react-native, abbyy

I have an react-native app and an existing java project ([Abbyy Real-Time Recognition SDK](http://rtrsdk.com/documentation/android-api-reference/)).

What I want is to integrate Abbyy with my react-native project and create than an NativeModule to communicate with ABBY.

Have anybody experience with that to show me a few hints?